# SonarQube error during NUnit test results import

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, nunit

I'm running SonarQube v 6.7.4 (build 38452) against .NET Core project with NUnit unit tests and OpenCover for coverage.
The scanner configuration listed below:

```
dotnet "C:\Sonar\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.2.0.1214-netcoreapp2.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin `
/n:XXXXX `
/v:XXXXX `
/key:XXXXX  `
/d:sonar.verbose=true `
/d:sonar.log.level=DEBUG `
/d:sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 `
/d:sonar.branch.name=develop `
/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=**/TestResults/*.trx `
/d:sonar.exclusions=**/Migrations/*.cs,**/coverage.opencover.xml `
/d:sonar.tests=**Tests/*.*,**/*.Tests/**/*.* `
/d:sonar.sources=. `
/d:sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/** `
/d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=**/coverage.opencover.xml `
/d:sonar.coverage.exclusions=**Tests/*.cs,**/Migrations/* `
/d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=**/TestResults/unit_tests.xml `
/d:sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/Migrations/*.cs `
/d:sonar.login=XXXXX

dotnet test XXXXXXX.sln --logger:"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover 


dotnet "C:\Sonar\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.2.0.1214-netcoreapp2.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" end `
/d:sonar.login=XXXXX
```

The following error is raised:

```
dotnet : 16:29:55.296 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet "C:\Sonar\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.4.2.1543- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (16:29:55.296 ER...anner execution:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.cxx.CxxPlugin$CxxMetricsImp
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:606)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponents(DefaultPicoContainer.java:587)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentsByType(ComponentContainer.java:274)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.addBatchExtensions(ProjectScanContainer.java:237)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:133)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectSettings
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 0: **Tests/*.*
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.resolvePath(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:395)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.logMissingPaths(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:355)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.logMissingSourcesAndTests(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:350)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.cleanAndCheckProjectDefinitions(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:336)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.execute(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:126)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.MutableProjectReactorProvider.provide(MutableProjectReactorProvider.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
    ... 69 more
Process returned exit code 1
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
16:29:55.377  Creating a summary markdown file...
16:29:55.379  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Here's the most interesting is the following line:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 0: **Tests/*.*
```

Seems the problem is with unit_tests.xml file format but I'm not sure.
I've tested the dotnet global tool (dotnet-scanner) and still the same error.